# What access does my company have to my corporate gmail account?

Tags: privacy, gmail

### Situation

I currently have a corporate address, which is facilitated by Google. My email address does not contain Gmail or google, but when I log in it shows a Google look and feel with minimal alterations (I can also go to drive for instance).

### Consideration

I am now wondering what kind of access the company has to my account. I came up with these ideas based on my image of what the world should look like:

#### 1. Things they cannot do

- Recover my password

#### 2. Things they can do, with me noticing

- Close my account
- Reset my password

#### 3. Things they can do, without me noticing

- Change rights to drive folders (to which I am currently the only one with access) in the shared drive
- Reopen the account and access everything after the account was closed due to me no longer needing it

In addition to this there are some things I don't know where to place:

- Access my drive content without me knowing
- Search my email
- Look at my history (search, phone location)  without changing my password
- Send emails from my account without changing my password
- Recover deleted mails/documents from beyond the point where I could have recovered them myself in a corporate or private account

### Question

Above I have indicated the most relevant points when it comes to Google corporate account access. Are my preconceptions correct and how do the unknowns fit in?

BONUS: Based on the above considerations, what is a shocking example of access types that corporates do/do not have?

---

Note that I am only interested in 'normal' access to my account, I am specifically not looking for anything that requires dodgy actions like abusing power over wifi/device.

Also, for those who wonder: I am not in trouble, just curious!

Answer (score 3):

This is [the business version of gmail](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/products/gmail/).

As mentioned in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28695/how-to-give-admin-access-to-all-users-mail), there's no direct way for a GSuite admin to log in to one of their users' accounts, but they can make use of [the auditing API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/) to download emails.

The easiest way to know if your IT admins can do something is to ask them. And you should generally assume that they have full access to anything you do on work accounts, on work computers, and on work networks - so don't do anything there that you wouldn't want them to potentially know.

Comment: The first part definitely resolves the 'search my mail' uncertainty. However, the second part assumes that an IT department is in place which knows exactly what is possible. In my case that route is not going to lead to an answer, so I think this is still only a partial answer.

Comment: Well, the practical answer depends on what it is you're trying to do.  Are you determining what your IT department can do, for personal privacy?  Or are you trying to determine how to store certain levels of company data to limit exposure in an admin account breach?

Comment: I am trying to determine what the IT department can do, for personal privacy. For instance because I am currently switching a lot between accounts on my phone (and may have re-used a password/logged my location for many days).